# Android app using ListView and SeekBar

Tags: usability, mobile, android

The user selects an item from the ListView (center content) then needs to select an amount using the slider (SeekBar) below. The problem is the layout also uses a ViewPager meaning that if you swipe left or right you will go to the next/previous page (see: Home, Inventory, Market)

This is clearly creating bad UX since if the user is sliding the SeekBar from left/right they can accidentally change pages.

Limited space to work with, clearly. At a loss here though since I need a horizontal slider. Any ideas? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This sounds like more of an implementation issue. The scope of that slide event should be limited to the slider and not also activate the view pager event listener. I don't know the equivalent function for your presumably Java application but you need something like this: [Event.StopPropogation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed it cause trouble.

2 solutions:

1. Ask your developer to make sure it works the way you want. Technically possible.
2. **Make the tap area bigger**. The circle on the slider that you drag has to be either equal or greater than a minimum advisable **touch target of 48DP.** This will help you a lot since the probability of touching the remaining screen will be less.

Anyways, testing is what will give you the perfect answer anyways. Go ahead and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Show a popup or may be a fragment on the bottom with seekbar when user selects an item from list item.
It should not be part of view pager. Something like [this](http://uigifs.com/agot-books/?utm_source=uiGIFs&utm_campaign=7486a0c405-Inbox_Pixels_Issue_28&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_30952f7950-7486a0c405-263213529)